How to prevent gsap functions from hiding NextUI navbar?
I'm trying to use a full screen scrolling feature on my Next.js website and I've found this code that uses gsap to achieve this:
https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/YzQOxxO
<section class="description panel blue">
  <div>
    <h1>Layered pinning</h1>
    <p>Use pinning to layer panels on top of each other as you scroll.</p>
    <div class="scroll-down">Scroll down<div class="arrow"></div></div>
  </div>
</section>


<section class="panel red">
    ONE
</section>
<section class="panel orange">
    TWO
</section>
<section class="panel purple">
    THREE
</section>
<section class="panel green">
    FOUR
</section>


<header>
   <a href="https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger">
     <img class="greensock-icon" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/scroll-trigger-logo-light.svg" width="200" height="64" />
  </a> 
</header>


gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

let scrollTween;

function goToSection(i) {
  scrollTween = gsap.to(window, {
    scrollTo: {y: i * innerHeight, autoKill: false},
    duration: 1,
    onComplete: () => scrollTween = null,
    overwrite: true
  });
}

gsap.utils.toArray(".panel").forEach((panel, i) => {
  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: panel,
    start: "top bottom-=2",
    end: () => "+=" + (window.innerHeight * 2 - 4),
    onToggle: self => self.isActive && !scrollTween && goToSection(i)
  });
});

window.addEventListener("wheel", cancelWhenTweening, {passive: false});
window.addEventListener("scroll", cancelWhenTweening, {passive: false});
function cancelWhenTweening(e) {
  scrollTween && e.preventDefault();
}

html, body { height: auto; }
.panel {
  height: 100vh;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

I've got the scrolling to work, but I'm also using NextUI's navbar component and when I scroll down from the first section, the navbar hides.
I've set the navbar's shouldHideOnScroll to false, but it still hides when I scroll to the second full page section. I think the gsap script is causing it, but I can't really solve it as I'm not the author of it.

did you added z-index to navbar?

i've tried that, but it didn't solve the issue. the issue is not caused by the navbar being obscured by something, it gets hidden. i've actually moved to fullpage.js, maybe i will have more luck with that...
